# Find file with asterisk

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find a file in subfolder.
Found this code, and with the full filename it works, but now I want to find the file with a partial I know.
Something like this:

```
 If myFile.Name = "*344148*" Then
```

But this is not working, below the complete code

```
Function Recurse(sPath As String) As String

    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim myFolder As Folder
    Dim mySubFolder As Folder
    Dim myFile As File

    Set myFolder = FSO.GetFolder(sPath)

    For Each mySubFolder In myFolder.SubFolders
        For Each myFile In mySubFolder.Files
        Debug.Print myFile.Name
        Debug.Print myFile
           ' If myFile.Name = "*" & Range("B2").Value & "*" Then
           ' If myFile = "*" & Range("B2").Value & "*" Then
            If myFile.Name = "*344148*" Then
                Debug.Print myFile.Name & " in " & myFile.Path 'Or do whatever you want with the file
                Workbooks.Open myFile.Path '& myFile.Name
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        Recurse = Recurse(mySubFolder.Path)
    Next

End Function

Sub TestR()

    Call Recurse("P:\NetworkLocation\")

End Sub
```

Comment: You want to use `Like`, not `=` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VBA: How to use like operator to a list of value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55144780/vba-how-to-use-like-operator-to-a-list-of-value)

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111227-00/?p=8793

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `If myFile.Name = "*344148*" Then` with `if instr(1,myFile.Name,"344148") <> 0 Then`